# Check array overlapping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, overlapping

I have some arrays like `[1,5], [3,6], [2,8],[19,13], [12,15]`. When i pass two arrays in the function output will be `[1,6], [2,19],[12,15]`

i want to remove overlapping numbers from 2 arrays . like on fist and second array 5 and 3 will be overlap between 1 to 6.

Comment: can you explain what happened about third and forth array??

Comment: Output will be 2,19 because 8 and 13 between 2 and 19

Comment: but they don't have overlap??

Comment: The problem is not clear to me. Can you explain which two arrays lead to which result? What is an overlapping number here?

Comment: I think I got our point now, but the question is still hard to understand. I suggest you to rewrite it. I will play a bit with that

Comment: @MahdyAslamy my initial guess is that 3 and 2 are smaller than 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want (you get the min of the first array and the max of the second array):

```js
function removeOverlap(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1 === undefined) {
    return arr2;
  }
  
  if (arr2 === undefined) {
    return arr1;
  }
  
  return [Math.min.apply(null, arr1), Math.max.apply(null, arr2)];
}

// Sample:
var myArrays = [[1,5], [3,6], [2,8], [19,13], [12,15]];

for (var i = 0; i < myArrays.length; i = i + 2) {
  console.log(removeOverlap(myArrays[i], myArrays[i + 1]));
}
```

**EDIT: answer with multiple parameters as you requested in your comment:**

We could use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in the answer below, but I will use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for compatibility with Internet Explorer. If this is not a requirement you can adapt the solution to use the first.

```js
function removeOverlap(arr1, arr2) {
  // Converting the arguments object to array:
  var argsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  // Removing undefined:
  argsArray = argsArray.filter(function(el) {
    return el != undefined;
  });

  // Alternative (not compatible with Internet Explorer):
  //argsArray = argsArray.filter(el => el);
  
  // We're looking for the min and max numbers, let's merge the arrays
  // e.g. transform [[1, 5], [3, 6], [2, 8]] into [1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 8] 
  var merged = [].concat.apply([], argsArray);

  // Alternative, but it is not compatible with Internet Explorer:
  //var merged = Array.flat(argsArray);
  
  return [Math.min.apply(null, merged), Math.max.apply(null, merged)];
}

// Sample:
var myArrays = [[1,5], [3,6], [2,8], [19,13], [12,15]];

for (var i = 0; i < myArrays.length; i = i + 2) {
  console.log(removeOverlap(myArrays[i], myArrays[i + 1]));
}

console.log(removeOverlap(myArrays[0], myArrays[1], myArrays[2]));
```

Comment: You answer is correct but if we pass 3 arguments in  "removeOverlap" method then what approach we will follow. Could you please help me.

Comment: @PriteshMahajan I am working on an update, but what should be the output for the following cases? (1) `removeOverlap([1,5], [10,67], [-2,8])` (2) `removeOverlap([1,5], [10,67])`

Comment: @PriteshMahajan I updated my answer with a version supporting multiple parameters. Check the alternatives to make your code simpler if compatibility is not an issue. It is a prerequisite that you are sure there are overlaps. The examples in my previous comment will fail

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be accomplished my finding the min of the current and max of the next item.

```js
let initial  = [ [1, 5], [3, 6], [2, 8], [19, 13], [12, 15] ]
let expected = [ [1, 6], [2, 19], [12, 15] ]
let actual   = calculateOverlaps(initial);

console.log(JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected)); // true

function calculateOverlaps(arr) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
    if (i >= arr.length - 1) {
      result.push(arr[i]); // If the array has an odd size, get last item
    } else {
      let curr = arr[i];
      let next = arr[i + 1];
      result.push([ Math.min(...curr), Math.max(...next) ]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here is a more code-golf oriented function:

```js
const calculateOverlaps1 = (arr) => arr.reduce((r, e, i, a) =>
  (i % 2 === 0)
    ? r.concat([
        (i < a.length - 1)
          ? [ Math.min(...e), Math.max(...a[i+1]) ]
          : e
      ])
    : r, []);
```

And even smaller, at just 101 bytes.

```js
f=a=>a.reduce((r,e,i)=>i%2===0?r.concat([i<a.length-1?[Math.min(...e),Math.max(...a[i+1])]:e]):r,[]);
```